# EclipseLink: onetomany relationships with lazy loading loaded with serialization

Tags: serialization, jpa, websphere, lazy-loading, eclipselink

I'm facing a problem with eclipselink under websphere 7.0 in a clustered environment. When my entity is serialized every 1-n relationship lazy is loaded, even if the entity is detached. How can I avoid this behavior, without having to use DTO?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you overwritten 'readObject/writeObject' or is the Entity Externalizable?  Make sure these methods are not triggering lazy relationships.